# How to use Neo4j in my java project

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I am new in using graph database.I recently read about neo4j graph database.I was doing a simple graph project in java using mysql. Now I want to use neo4j but initially I am finding it a bit difficult. I searched and I found that I need to create a maven project for it. Is it necessary? If not, how to include neo4j lib files to get started.I have downloaded neo4j community and installed it correctly.I think I just need to include the proper files.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Seriously, if you're not familiar with build tools like maven or gradle, it's definitely worth investing some time to learn those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [check the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html) there's an answer there for you.

If you download the tar.gz or ZIP distribution of neo4j, it comes with a "lib" directory.  To use neo4j in your project, just make sure all of the `.jar` files in the `lib` directory are in your `CLASSPATH`, and you're done.

So no, you don't have to use maven.  But if you're going to develop java applications of any size, I'd recommend learning maven and doing it that route anyway since maven makes managing your dependencies and setting your classpath much easier than doing it yourself by hand.  Doing it yourself is no big deal if you're managing a dependency or two, but it becomes a big problem if you have many dependencies and tools like maven make it really simple.

Comment: Thank you! but when I downloaded it it was an installer which installed directly with no zip file.So the folder named Neo4j community was added in my program files(x86) folder,which does not have lib directory.So I am facing the problem from where exactly to add .jar files

Comment: you can still download the zip file separately. And I agree with Stefan, use maven or gradle to manage you dependencies.